# Is it possible to change a villagers profession using /event?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im making a world that depends on certain villager professions to make it work best. Can you use the /event command to change a villagers profession?

Answer (score 1):

Yup
`/event entity @e[name=test,type=villager] minecraft:become_<profession>`
just change the `<profession>` with the profession you want