# Why is my iron farm not working in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make an iron farm for a survival world, but I want a secret resource bunker for me and whoever finds it. I don’t know why my farm isn’t working, I tried redoing it many times. Ideas? I've got three villagers, the bare minimum, eight zombies, because why not, and double the amount of beds times villagers. My game is up to date, if that matters.
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly we're looking at, how your farm functions?

Comment: So, my farm is basically the villagers are stuck on the top of the farm, and have double the beds because I heard that that is what you need. Right next to them, is a room of zombies, only blocked by a slab. I spawn-proofed the platform, so golems won't spawn there. However, no golems are even spawning.

Answer (score 3):

Your current set-up seems to be based on a *Java* Edition farm. In Java Edition, you can indeed spawn a golem with only three villagers if they are panicking, e.g. because of nearby zombies. But the rules for Bedrock Edition are significantly different. (All current mobile and console versions of the game fall under Bedrock Edition.)

I am following the details given in the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Villages).

###### Size of village

First, you need at least 10 villagers and 20 beds to spawn a golem in Bedrock Edition. So you need to expand your setup significantly.

###### Villager Jobs

In addition, 75% of the villagers must have worked at their workstation in the past day. I don't know how unemployed villagers factor into that formula, but your villagers do have jobs, based on their outfits. Assuming you haven't traded with them, they will switch to new jobs once you provide them with accessible job blocks. (If you *have* traded with them, then they are locked in to their current jobs, so you will need to specifically provide them with job blocks that match the jobs they already have.)

###### Golem spawn distances

Golems don't spawn more than 6 blocks below (or above) the village center. In this case your pit appears to be an appropriate depth, but it's something to be aware of going forward. You may also want to make the pit bigger, so it surrounds the beds on all sides; this should increase your golem spawn rates.

###### Zombies

You can remove the zombies. They have no effect.

---

Further details can be found at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming#Bedrock_Edition.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to make this happen, and will put a picture down later if it still doesn't work, one thing though, is my villagers have jobs no matter what. If I'm in a flat world with no job blocks, they still spawn with a job whether i use commands, or spawn eggs. If you could tell me why, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't aware that villagers in Bedrock spawn with jobs (I don't really play with spawn eggs or command blocks much myself), but apparently that's just [a thing that happens](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-46034). I've edited my answer slightly to address this.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but that's another thing. My villagers won't take a new job or get unemployed. I haven't traded with them, and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @T1tan-FearLeSS Hmm...that might be a bug. Other people are mentioning the same problem in [the bug ticket I linked earlier](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-46034). Can they reach/walk up to the job blocks? Have you tried giving them blocks that match the professions they already have? If that doesn't work, you could try either A) finding an existing village and stealing some villagers from there, or B) spawning some zombie villagers and then curing them. Or...

Comment: @T1tan-FearLeSS ...you could try using a [spawn event](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Spawn_event) with the `/event` command to make your villagers unemployed, which might force them to pick a new job. `/event entity @e[type=villager,r=10] minecraft:become_unskilled` should convert all villagers within 10 blocks of you. See also https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391552/is-it-possible-to-change-a-villagers-profession-using-event

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an iron farm in Bedrock Edition, you need to have a full village (at least 10 villagers), and beds (at least 10).

You got the part right where you need to add water to the bottom and barricade the surrounding area (so the golem can't spawn outside of the area). However, I would recommend adding leaves outside of the hole (if you haven't already). The zombies are **unnecessary**, as villager fear only works on Java Edition.